# How to implement multiple timers in C?

Tags: c

What is the best way to implement timers in C?

I need to set few timers which can expire at different times to indicate various events. I would like some callback to be fired upon timer expiry.

I see that C supports alarm base timer which generates a SIGALRM after the timer expiry. But i see that i can use only one alarm per process.

Any other way to fire up multiple timers ?